# How to replace keywords in dict values in list of dicts (with case insensitivity)?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list of keywords:

```
keywords = ["test", "Ok", "great stuff", "PaaS", "mydata"]
```

And a list of dicts:

```
statements = [
{"id":"1","text":"Test, this is OK, great stuff, PaaS."},
{"id":"2","text":"I would like to test this, Great stuff."}
]
```

**Desired Behavior**

When the `keyword` is present in `statement['text']` (regardless of case), I want to replace the keyword with a "marked up" version of the keyword, ie the matched keyword `Test` would become:

```
<span class="my_class" data-mydata="<a href=&quot;#&quot;>test</a>">Test</span>
```

**What I've Tried**

Below is what I've tried, the observations/considerations being:

**01)**  It is not replacing the keywords.

**02)**  If it was, once the markup is applied, I do not want matches occuring within the markup - ie the `mydata` within the markup should not be matched.

**03)**  I may have started out in the wrong direction with this, and need to redesign the logic from the start.

**Python 2.7 Code**

```
import re

keywords = ["test", "ok", "great stuff", "paas"]

statements = [
{"id":"1","text":"Test, this is OK, great stuff, PaaS."},
{"id":"2","text":"I would like to test this, Great stuff."}
]

keyword_markup = {}

print "\nKEYWORDS (all lowercase):\n"

for i in keywords:
    print "\"" + i + "\" "

print "\nORIGINAL STATEMENTS:\n"

for statement in statements:
    print statement['text'] + "\n"

statement_counter = 1
# for each statement
for statement in statements:
    print "\nIN STATEMENT " + str(statement_counter) + ": \n"
    # get the original statement
    original_statement = statement['text']
    # for each keyword in the keyword list
    for keyword in keywords:
        # if the keyword is not in the keyword_markup dict
        # add it (with a lowercase key)
        if keyword.lower() not in keyword_markup:
            keyword_markup[keyword.lower()] = "<span class=\"my_class\" data-mydata=\"<a href=&quot;#&quot;>" + keyword + "</a>\">" + keyword + "</span>"
            print "The key added to the keyword_markup dict is: " + keyword.lower()
        # if the keyword is in a lowercase version of the statement
        if keyword in original_statement.lower():
            # sanity check - print the matched keyword
            print "The keyword matched in the statement is: " + keyword
            # change the text value of the statement "in place"
            # by replacing the keyword, with its marked up equivalent.
            # using the original_statement as the source string
            statement['text'] = re.sub(keyword,keyword_markup[keyword.lower()],original_statement)
    statement_counter += 1

print "\nMARKED UP KEYWORDS AVAILABLE:\n"

for i in keyword_markup:
    print keyword_markup[i]

print "\nNEW STATEMENTS:\n"

for statement in statements:
    print statement['text'] + "\n"
```

**Results**

```
KEYWORDS (all lowercase):

"test" 
"ok" 
"great stuff" 
"paas" 

ORIGINAL STATEMENTS:

Test, this is OK, great stuff, PaaS.

I would like to test this, Great stuff.


IN STATEMENT 1: 

The key added to the keyword_markup dict is: test
The keyword matched in the statement is: test
The key added to the keyword_markup dict is: ok
The keyword matched in the statement is: ok
The key added to the keyword_markup dict is: great stuff
The keyword matched in the statement is: great stuff
The key added to the keyword_markup dict is: paas
The keyword matched in the statement is: paas

IN STATEMENT 2: 

The keyword matched in the statement is: test
The keyword matched in the statement is: great stuff

MARKED UP KEYWORDS AVAILABLE:

<span class="my_class" data-mydata="<a href=&quot;#&quot;>test</a>">test</span>
<span class="my_class" data-mydata="<a href=&quot;#&quot;>paas</a>">paas</span>
<span class="my_class" data-mydata="<a href=&quot;#&quot;>ok</a>">ok</span>
<span class="my_class" data-mydata="<a href=&quot;#&quot;>great stuff</a>">great stuff</span>

NEW STATEMENTS:

Test, this is OK, great stuff, PaaS.

I would like to test this, Great stuff.
```

Comment: Have you tried tokenizing your input, marking up special tokens, then reassembly the tokens into the output? https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#writing-a-tokenizer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this without regular expressions, though re.sub or re.findall with re.IGNORECASE would be a good place to start (as you discovered) if that's the direction you want to go.

I also started thinking about writing a one-pass tokenizer, but decided a multi-pass system was simpler to understand and maintain than some ugly state machine.

The code below is optimized for readability, not performance.

```
def main():
    keywords = ["test", "ok", "great stuff", "paas"]

    statements = [
        {"id":"1","text":"Test, this is OK, great stuff, PaaS."},
        {"id":"2","text":"I would like to test this, Great stuff."}
    ]

    for statement in statements:
        m = markup_statement(statement['text'], keywords)
        print('id={}, text={}'.format(statement['id'], m))
```

Produces the following output:

```
id=1, text=<a href="#">Test</a>, this is <a href="#">OK</a>, <a href="#">great stuff</a>, <a href="#">PaaS</a>.
id=2, text=I would like to <a href="#">test</a> this, <a href="#">Great stuff</a>.
```

Here are the supporting functions:

```
def markup_statement(statement, keywords):
    """Returns a string where keywords in statement are marked up

    >>> markup_statement('ThIs is a tEst stAtement', ['is', 'test'])
    'Th<a href="#">Is</a> <a href="#">is</a> a <a href="#">tEst</a> stAtement'
    """
    markedup_statement = []
    keywords_lower = {k.lower() for k in keywords}
    for token in tokenize(statement, keywords):
        if token.lower() in keywords_lower:
            markedup_statement.append(markup(token))
        else:
            markedup_statement.append(token)
    return ''.join(markedup_statement)

def markup(keyword):
    """returns the marked up version of a keyword/token (retains the original case)
    This function provides the same markup regardless of keyword, but it could be
    modified to provide keyword-specific markup

    >>> markup("tEst")
    '<a href="#">tEst</a>'
    """
    return '<a href="#">{}</a>'.format(keyword)
```

This tokenizer makes multiple passes over the statement, one pass for each keyword. The order of keywords may affect the tokens returned by `tokenize`. For example, if the markup replacement function is `markup = {'at': lambda x: '@', 'statement': lambda x: '<code>{}</code>'.format(x)}.get` then `'This is a statement statement'` could either be `'This is a st@ement'` or `'This is a <code>statement</code>'`.

```
def tokenize(statement, keywords):
    """Adapted from https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#writing-a-tokenizer
    Splits statement on keywords
    Assumes that there is no overlap between keywords in statement

    >>> tokenize('ThIs is a tEst stAtement', ['is', 'test'])
    ['Th', 'Is', ' ', 'is', ' a ', 'tEst', ' stAtement']
    >>> ''.join(tokenize(statement, keywords)) == statement
    True
    """
    statement_fragments = [statement]
    for keyword in keywords:
        statement_fragments = list(split(statement_fragments, keyword))
    return statement_fragments
```

This is not a particularly fast splitter, but is simple enough to explain the idea. I could have used `re.split(pattern, string, flags=re.IGNORECASE)` here, but I avoid regular expressions when vanilla python logic works, since regex code is seldom readable and not particularly fast.

```
def split(statement_fragments, keyword):
    """Split each statement fragment by keywords
    statement_fragments: list of strings
    keyword: string
    returns list of strings, which may be the same length or longer than statement_fragments

    This repeatedly trims and lowercases strings. If it's a bottleneck,
    rewrite it with a start and end index slices

    >>> split(['ThIs is a tEst stAtement'], 'is')
    ['Th', 'Is', ' ', 'is', ' a tEst stAtement']
    """
    keyword_lower = keyword.lower()
    length = len(keyword)
    for fragment in statement_fragments:
        i = fragment.lower().find(keyword_lower)
        while i != -1:
            yield fragment[:i]
            yield fragment[i:i+length]
            fragment = fragment[i+length:]
            i = fragment.lower().find(keyword_lower)
        # yield whatever is left over
        yield fragment
```

Without comments, that's around 30 lines of code with no imports.

Comment: It will take me a few hours to fully understand and appreciate this as it is a bit above my skillset, but thank you.  Kudos for readability considerations! I have made some amendments and it is working as expected.  In `markup()` function, I replaced this:  `return '<a href="#">{}</a>'.format(keyword)` with this: `return '<span class="my_class" data-mydata="<a href=\'#\'>{}</a>">{}</span>'.format(keyword.lower(), keyword)` , and I wanted to make dict value changes persistent in the `statements` array, so I replaced the `print` statement in `main()` with `statement['text'] = m` and it worked!